# Get all possible outputs from a set of inputs in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file called `recipes.csv`:

```
name,alternate,time,ingredients,products,producedIn,classifiedAs
Iron Plate,False,6,30.0x Iron Ingot,20.0x Iron Plate,Constructor,Iron
Iron Rod,False,4,15.0x Iron Ingot,15.0x Iron Rod,Constructor,Iron
Wire,False,4,15.0x Copper Ingot,30.0x Wire,Constructor,Copper...
```

I can't find a way to get the possible results with a set of inputs as a dictionary where the keys are the recipes and the value is the number of said recipies that can be made with the desired inputs. An example:
Input:

```py
{'Iron Ingot':60, 'Copper Ingot':20}
```

Desired output:

```py
[
    {'Iron Plate':2, 'Wire':1, 'Leftover':{'Copper Ingot':5}},
    {'Iron Rod':4, 'Wire':1, 'Leftover':{'Copper Ingot':5}},
    {'Iron Plate':1,'Iron Rod':2, 'Wire':1, 'Leftover':{'Copper Ingot':5}},
]
```

My code:

```py
import csv
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("recipes.csv", usecols = ['name','ingredients', 'products'])

# Original Header: ['name', 'alternate', 'time', 'ingredients', 'products', 'producedIn', 'classifiedAs']
# New Header: ['name', 'ingredients', 'products']
# Iron Plate: #139
# Iron Rod: #140
# Wire: #214

df.to_csv('recipes_new.csv')

with open('recipes_new.csv') as csvFile:
    recipes = csv.reader(csvFile)

    # Print out recipes:
    i = 0
    for row in recipes:
        print(row)
        i += 1
```

Comment: Post your code?

Comment: Done. I keep on forgetting to do that.

Comment: What’s the relationship between the values in recipes and your desired output? I don’t understand how all the numbers relate. Thank you.

Comment: @ZachYoung I'm making this for a game called Satisfactory, where you build factories. The recipes are what the machines in the game use. The numbers are the amount of that item per minute. I hope this answers your question.